# primer programa error callable

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo mi primer programa de Python:

```
n=4
print(n)
```

⠀

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

No estoy llamando a ninguna librería y quizás sea el problema.

Comment: El código es correcto para la ejecución sin errores. ¿Tienes Python instalado? ¿Qué editor usas?

Comment: Sospecho que ese no es el código que estabas ejecutando, pues ese es correcto. Quizás lo que ejecutabas era algo como `print n()`? python2?

Comment: Eso es lo único que tienes??

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias

Answer (score -5, accepted):

No puedes hacer n = 4 print(n). Si quieres hacerlo en una línea n = 4; print(n), pero no lo recomendaría.

 Una variable solo puede almacenar valores de su tipo, no puedes hacer llamadas desde variables.

[Este link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp) te será de ayuda para entenderlo correctamente.
Tienes que hacerlo de esta forma

```
n = 4
print(n)
```

[image: Captura]

Comment: ha sido  al escribir la pregunta, lo tengo hecho como me dices tu y me da ese error. por eso digo que si pudiera ser por alguna libreria

Comment: No necesitas llamar a ninguna libreria para esto. Podrias editar tu pregunta y subir el codigo. Que IDE estas utilizando?

Comment: he hecho uno nuevo y ya funciona. muchas gracias